# String as Id for Spring entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying create entity with String id:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class Account {

    @Id
    private String username;

    private String password;

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this(username, username + "pass");
    }

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

But I can't save this entity: `accounts.save(new Account(name, pass));`
Error: `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():`

What's wrong?

Comment: did you check that username is not null?

Comment: are you passing `username` while saving the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign ids automatically on save then you must annotate ID column with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`